# Function returns an unexpected value

Tags: perl

```
sub func1
    {
      my $x = shift;
      #print("\n$x\n");
      ++$x;
      #print("\n$x\n");
      $x++;
      #print ("\n$x\n");
     }

my ($v1) = func1(5);
print("this is op: $v1");
```

The output is:

`this is op: 6`

- This is my Perl program which is printing value 6 as output.
- But, I am unable to understand how the value six is coming. I have not used any `print` statement or `return` statement in my function, and I have incremented the value of x two times.  Why is it giving 6 as output instead of 7?

Answer (score 4):

It is a good practice to use an explicit `return` statement in the `sub` to avoid issues like this.  The following prints `7`:

```
sub func1
    {
      my $x = shift;
      #print("\n$x\n");
      ++$x;
      #print("\n$x\n");
      $x++;
      #print ("\n$x\n");
      return $x;
     }

my ($v1) = func1(5);
print("this is op: $v1");
```

From [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement):

> "++" and "--" work as in C. That is, if placed before a variable, they
> increment or decrement the variable by one before returning the value,
> and if placed after, increment or decrement after returning the value.

`$x++` is the last statement in your sub. In the absence of a `return`, Perl returns the value returned by the last expression it evaluated. `$x++` and thus the sub returns the value of `$x` **before** it is incremented.

From [perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub):

> If no return is found and if the last statement is an expression, its
> value is returned.

Comment: The `return` is kind of a red-herring. Like consider what would happen if you replaced `$x++; return $x;` with `return $x++;` (the "bug" starts occurring again) or `$x++; $x;` (it fixes the "bug").

Comment: A common style, that I use, is to only use explicit return for early returns, otherwise use the last expression.